# Нужно изменить каждый элемент списка

Tags: python-3.x, списки

Всем привет. Есть список:

```
IDs = ['6cSJFEwQzZM', 'r96Q1tKw9oY', 'H8eIupPlQVg', 'KByCbXko4mA', '2DLUCTayMJk', 'GPCAj2tk4_0', '15U_Zwh0rrQ', 'mHFeowJYiRk', 'QA6gHHyHNO8', 'LVrVcoQvZL8']
```

к каждому элементу списка необходимо добавить `https:\\www.mysite.com\`
Я понимаю, что задача, скорее всего, не очень сложная, но в интернете не очень могу найти информацию. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: в чём у вас конкретное затруднение? Ясно ли как одну строку к другой добавить в Питоне? Ясно ли как в цикле  обойти все элементы списка?

Comment: как строки прибавить я понимаю, а вот как циклом обойти, не до конца. Появляется ошибка, что-то вроде. нельзя складывать список и строку

Comment: `new = [url + i for i in IDs]`

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: @MaxU: чтобы "изменить": `IDS[:] = [url + id for id in IDS]`

Comment: @jfs, я в курсе, но я бы список `ID` оставил - наверняка он в нескольких местах будет использоваться...

Comment: @MaxU тогда вопрос должен быть "как создать список с таким-то элементами", а не как *изменить* элементы списка.

Comment: На самом деле и так и так меня устроит, так как, данные берутся из парсинга текста, поэтому второй раз текст спарсить можно. Все-равно максимальное кол-во элементов будет в крайнем случае 10, с обновлением не чаще раза в 15 минут

Comment: если думаете, что нашли решение, то опубликуйте его в виде своего ответа -- [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот код подошел:

```html
list_short_link = ['https://youtu.be/' + i for i in video_ID]
```